I am not sure about the use of 'polytomous' in this context in a scientific paper. Can someone help me find the proper word for this context?
This is the text:

As shown in Table 2 and Figure 3, our subgroup analysis of studies midpoint was not statistically significant (p=0.92). This finding was further supported with univariate and multivariate random-effect meta-regression (Table 3), indicating the absence of a linear or polytomous (cutoffs: 2005 and 2015) temporal pattern of ICP incidence (p=0.15 and p=0.78, respectively).

Context: I did my analysis by dividing subjects into three categories: <2005, 2005-2014, and 2015-2023 and there was no difference between the subjects in each group, indicating that there was no time trend based on this kind of classification.
I am not sure if the correct word to use here is polytomous. I tried to use ChatGPT to get more options but it didn't work well. I also asked this question on English StackExchange but got no answer yet.

I think the English is fine, obnoxious word-choice, sure, but technically correct use of the word.
This word refers to having multiple categories and is sometimes used to describe regression models with categorical outcomes, since multinomial distributions generalize binomial distributions, not just Bernoulli (multiple roles of a die are possible, not just one roll that would give a single category).
Statistically, they mean that there is not a linear trend over time. Also, when the time is bucketed into multiple chunks (categories), the categories are not found to differ. This is the polytomous relationship (or lack of a relationship).
Unless this is a common phrasing in the field, which your confusion about its meaning suggests is not the case, I think there are better ways to phrase the passage.

There are probably better ways of doing the time series or panel data analysis, but that is its own distinct topic.

"Polytomous" is the natural generalization of "dichotomous."  Both derive from Indo-European words for cutting (which is insightful) and, of course, "di" means "two" and "poly" means many.
